# B-rated horror movie with a character who has no arms and is like a worm person

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm looking for a B-rated horror movie possibly named "Freaks", but I can't find it by Googling it.

One character has no arms and is like a worm person. I only saw it once but the worm guy is always asking people to wipe his butt.

What is the name of the movie and does anyone know the director?

Comment: Hello Justin. As this site is about [fantasy.se], can you please indicate what makes the film you're looking for fantastical or science fictional? Or — a bit broader — a work of speculative fiction?

Comment: I just started this account tonight for the walking dead and  And science fiction knowledge.  I am a very big walking dead fan. And have loved everything science fiction since I was young.  I thought horror was included.  I am also a huge B - rated horror movie fan.  If this question was an appropriate for the site I apologize

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: I believe the movie you're looking for is "Freaked" (1993). It's a sci-fi comedy and it does begin and maybe? end on a plane and it has a 'worm' guy.

Comment: Hey Justin, if you do decide to [edit] the question, could you please take a look at [our guide on asking story IDs](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561)? Perhaps you can add some more details.

Comment: @SQB - There seems to be sufficient weirdness going on here to count as fantasy horror in my books. The fact that the protagonists have turned out to be real "freaks" is doubly surprising but that doesn't put this off-topic

Comment: Hey Justin, did you happen to catch the latest answer? I think there's a good chance that it's the film you're looking for. (If so, please click the checkmark next to it).

Answer (score 5):

"Freaked" (1993)?

This cult classic comedy is B grade and has a title that is close to the one you remember and it has a worm-like character. I downloaded the trailer from YouTube and you can see a few quick shots of the worm character at 1:14.

The entire movie is also available on YouTube. I went through it and found the worm-guy character saying "I'd sell my soul just to be able to wipe my own ass" at 28:20. Here is the movie.

Comment: "Just because a guy doesn't like macaroons..."

Answer (score 4):

This could very well be *[Freaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freaks)*, a 1932 movie by Tod Browning. It has the title and the freaks (real freaks, which freaked the audience out — pun intended). It has been decades since I saw it, so I don't remember the butt-wiping scene; but then, the movie exists in several cuts, and the scene may be from a longer version than the one I saw.

[image: movie poster for Freaks]

From Wikipedia:

> The central story is of this conniving trapeze artist named Cleopatra, who seduces and marries the sideshow midget Hans after learning of his large inheritance. Cleopatra conspires with circus strongman Hercules to kill Hans and inherit his wealth. At their wedding reception, Cleopatra begins poisoning Hans' wine. Oblivious, the other "freaks" announce that they accept Cleopatra in spite of her being a "normal" outsider: they hold an initiation ceremony in which they pass a loving cup around the table while chanting, "We accept her, we accept her. One of us, one of us. Gooba-gobble, gooba-gobble". The ceremony frightens the drunken Cleopatra, who accidentally reveals that she has been having an affair with Hercules. She mocks the freaks, tosses the wine in their faces and drives them away. The humiliated Hans realizes that he has been played for a fool and rejects Cleopatra's attempts to apologize, but then he falls ill from the poison.
>
> While bedridden, Hans pretends to apologize to Cleopatra and also pretends to take the poisoned medicine that she is giving him, but he secretly plots with the other freaks to strike back at Cleopatra and Hercules. In the film's climax, the freaks attack the evil pair during a storm, wielding guns, knives, and other sharp-edged weapons. After trying to kill seal trainer Venus and her clown boyfriend Phroso for knowing about the plot, Hercules is chased by the freaks in a storm and not seen again (the film's original ending had the freaks castrating him: the audience see him later singing in falsetto). As for Cleopatra, she has become a grotesque, squawking "human duck". The flesh of her hands has been melted and deformed to look like duck feet, her legs have been cut off and what is left of her torso has been permanently tarred and feathered.

This may be the "worm guy" you're thinking of:

Comment: Also, I wouldn't call it B-rated by any account.

Comment: No this isnt it......i think the movie ended on a plane.... This has been bugging me for a long time I'm starting to wonder if it was in a dream i had!! Lol  Also the one I'm thinking of was filmed in the seventies or eighties

Comment: It's a *bit* difficult to credit a memorable recurring element of a character asking others to wipe his butt as part of a 1932 movie. By the 1970s or 1980s, it's much more credible.